# How to get date and time in below format in java?

Tags: java, datetime-format, current-time

How can I get the current date and time and how can I transfer it into the following String format?

06-04-2020 05:00 PM

After that I need to add few minutes to the date? Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How have you tried to get it? What went wrong? Any error or empty output? Can you show us your code?

Comment: have you done any search on this site?

Comment: And please add what's exactly meant by *get ... in ... format*... Do you have to parse or output a datetime?

Comment: dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a

Comment: You guys are so annoying with your downvotes. This is a valid and good question for java beginners! I would recommend looking up `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting the date into that string. Also, you can simply get the CURRENT date and time with a call like this: `Date d = new Date();`Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Guys, I have tried simpledateformat, calendar as well as local date. However, the point is I need to add few minutes to the date and I need in the desire format mentioned above.

Comment: @F_Schmidt Thanks for your kind concern! I have managed to get it now!

Comment: @F_Schmidt I didn’t downvote, but this question certainly deserves downvotes for lack of shown search and research effort. I agree that a constructive criticism in a comment is better than a downvote (or one may provide both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer should look something like this:

```
String dateTimePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimePattern );
LocalDateTime yourDay= LocalDateTime.of(2020, 4, 6, 17, 00);
System.out.println(formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.of(yourDay, ZoneId.of("UTC-5"))));
```

Please look [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) up for more info on the available formats.

Comment: Where does the information about the time zone come from?

Comment: It was a simple assumption, the question is how to format, not in which timezone the OP is.

Comment: Yes, no problem... just wanted to know... This is not a bad answer, but adding information that wasn't explicitly desired is somehow exe-catching ;-)

Comment: I did not wanted timezone!

Comment: To add minutes, or any time units in general, try ```LocalDateTime example = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5);```

Comment: @PaianganuOm Thanks a ton! I managed to get the minutes with the above function now! :)

Comment: Adding a time zone is a good idea for many purposes. Prefer for example `America/Chicago` over `UTC-5`, that is *region/city* format.

Answer (score 2):

```
Date yourDate = new Date();  
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h:m a");  
String formatedDate= sdf.format(yourDate);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.