# Date Formating:I would like to obtain the following date format 25/11/1990 14:35 based on a Timestamp of format '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000'

Tags: java, angular6, datetime-format

I would like to obtain the following date format 25/11/1990 14:35 based on a Timestamp of format '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000'.

It needs to be done either via Angular 6 or Java 8.

Please provide any relevant solutions.

My Approach:

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("1990-11-25 01:02:03.123456789")//Value from Db.
String str = timestamp.tostring();
str.substring();
```

This is helping me for displaying to the user but as I am converting it to a string I am unable to store it in DB Since DB will only store Timestamp format.

Comment: Please provide any relevant attempts that you have made. This is not code for hire, what have you tried? what issues did you encounter?

Comment: I answered a similar question today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058640/how-to-get-date-and-time-in-below-format-in-java/61058713#61058713

Comment: @AshleyMedway I am trying to convert the Timestamp into a String using tostring() method and format it Using substring, "timestamp.toString()". While it displays to the user via this method. When I try to edit the record and send it to Db it no longer works as in the DB the column is specified as Timestamp and I am sending a string value.

Comment: When you say Timestamp, did you mean `java.sql.Timestamp`? I recommend you don’t use that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead retrieve your timestamp as either an `OffsetDateTime` (for timestamp with time zone) or a `LocalDateTime` (for without time zone) from your database. Both classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time and JDBC 4.2

I warmly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work, not the old `Timestamp` class. This example snippet includes how you retrieve the timestamp from your database and format it for the user:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("pt"));

    PreparedStatement query = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "select your_timestamp_column from your_table where id = 4;");
    ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        OffsetDateTime dateTime
                = rs.getObject("your_timestamp_column", OffsetDateTime.class);
        String str = dateTime.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Example output would be

> 25/11/1990 14:35

Please insert the language tag of your user where I put `pt` (for Portuguese). Or leave out the `withLocale` call to rely on the default locale of your JVM. And note the use of `getObject()` rather than `getTimestamp()`.

I have used `OffsetDateTime` in the code based on the assumption that the datatype in your database is `timestamp with time zone`, which is what is recommended for timestamps. In this case you may also want to convert the timestamp to the user’s time zone before formatting it.

If the datatype is `timestamp` without time zone, instead use `LocalDateTime` in exactly the same manner.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.